# Change form method depending on pressed button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form containing filters and table with checkboxes for different "bulk" actions. Bulk actions should be posted via POST, filters - GET guery. I cannot use 2 different forms and don't want to post actions/filters using AJAX, so I decided to change the form METHOT attribute depending on which button is pressed.

```
$('button.filter').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').attr('method', 'get');
});
```

Basically it works, at least in Opera. I just wondering is this method correct? Any other solutions?

UPD: I decided to simple emulate GET request. Looks less hacky to me

```
$('thead :submit').click(function () {
    var params = $(this).closest('thead').find(':input[name]').filter(function () {
        return this.value !== "";
    }).serialize();

    if(params){
        window.location = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?' + params;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: This method looks OK

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain JavaScript if you don't want to use jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("form").method = "post";
```